# How to run multiple Livewire components in the same view (without nesting)

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a simple view where I need to run these 2 scripts but **it executes only the first one**, if I change the order only "post-image" is executed...

```
@extends('template')

@section('content')

    <livewire:post-tags />
    <livewire:post-image />

@endsection
```

I could make just one component but later on, I would need to run multiple independent components on the same page. The livewire documentation does not show explicitly how to do this without using nesting, and I'd rather not nest scripts if I don't need to.

Comment: Stab in the dark, either try `@livewire('post-tags')` `@livewire('post-image')` or `<livewire:post-tags></livewire><livewire:post-image></livewire>`

Comment: I did try both and the funny part is that it actually works on a separated test project but it does not work in the one I am working on.. :/

Comment: Strange, my two suggestions didn't work either? Did you check the laravel log or the dev JS console, anything there maybe? Couldn't think of anything else, sorry

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out to be a DOM Diffing issue. I solved this by wrapping the 2 parts of the code in their own div with a wire:key. I overlooked this part of the documentation, it doesn't really explain why it works but it did at least for me: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/troubleshooting